# (FIXED) How do I make my discord.py bot play a sound effect?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

My bot is supposed to be some sort of jeopardy quiz show type of bot. /joinvc makes the bot connect to the call, however, I cant seem to make the bot make noise when its in a vc. Here's some of the code:

```
@interactions.slash_command(
    name="press",
    description="Press the button"
)

async def press(ctx: interactions.ComponentContext):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has pressed the button")
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('audiopath', after=lambda: print('done'))
    player.start()
```

But whenever I use the /press command, I get this error `AttributeError: 'GuildVoice' object has no attribute 'create_ffmpeg_player'`

Is it something I did wrong with ffmpeg?

I tried using a different way to write the code, basically grabbing the ffmpeg.exe path and the audio path, didn't work either. I just want the bot to play a small noise whenever someone uses /press command.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the first example at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/migrating.html#voice-changes

Comment: tried it, then i got the error "vc = await channel.connect NameError: name 'channel' is not defined"